# I am trying to interpolate a value from a pandas dataframe using numpy.interp but it continuously returns a wrong interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# defining a function for interpolation
def interpolate(x, df, xcol, ycol):
    return np.interp([x], df[xcol], df[ycol])

# function call
print(interpolate(0.4, freq_data, 'Percent_cum_freq', 'cum_OGIP'))
```

Trying a more direct method:

```
print(np.interp(0.4, freq_data['Percent_cum_freq'], freq_data['cum_OGIP']))
```

Output:

```
from function [2.37197912e+10]
from direct 23719791158.266743
```

For any values of x that I pass: `0.4, 0.6 and 0.9`, it gives the same result, that is, 2.37197912e+10
freq_data dataframe

```
Percent_cum_freq      cum_OGIP
0              0.999  4.455539e+07
1              0.981  1.371507e+08
2              0.913  2.777860e+08
3              0.824  4.664612e+08
4              0.720  7.031764e+08
5              0.615  9.879315e+08
6              0.547  1.320727e+09
7              0.464  1.701562e+09
8              0.396  2.130436e+09
9              0.329  2.607351e+09
10             0.285  3.132306e+09
11             0.245  3.705301e+09
12             0.199  4.326336e+09
13             0.167  4.995410e+09
14             0.136  5.712525e+09
15             0.115  6.477680e+09
16             0.085  7.290874e+09
17             0.072  8.152108e+09
18             0.056  9.061383e+09
19             0.042  1.001870e+10
20             0.034  1.102405e+10
21             0.027  1.207745e+10
22             0.022  1.317888e+10
23             0.015  1.432835e+10
24             0.013  1.552587e+10
25             0.010  1.677142e+10
26             0.007  1.806502e+10
27             0.002  1.940665e+10
28             0.002  2.079632e+10
29             0.002  2.223404e+10
30             0.001  2.371979e+10
```

What is wrong? How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was as well surprised by the results when I implemented the code you provided. After a little search on the [documentation for np.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) , found that **the x-coordinates must be always increasing**.

```
np.interp(x,list_of_x_coordinates,list_of_y_coordinates)
```

Where `x` is the value you want the value of y at.

`list_of_x_coordinates` is `df[xcol]` -> **This must always be increasing**. **But as your dataframe is decreasing, it will never give correct result.**

`list_of_y_coordinates` is `df[ycol]` -> This must be of same dimension and in order with the df[xcol]

My reproduced code:

```
import numpy as np
list_1=np.interp([0.1,0.5,0.8],[0.999,0.547,0.199,0.056,0.013,0.001],[4.455539e+07,1.320727e+09,4.326336e+09,9.061383e+09,1.552587e+10, 2.371979e+10])

list_2=np.interp([0.1,0.5,0.8],[0.001,0.013,0.056,0.199,0.547,0.999],[2.371979e+10,1.552587e+10,9.061383e+09,4.326336e+09,1.320727e+09,4.455539e+07])
print("In decreasing order -> As in your case",list_1)
print("In increasing order of x xoordinates",list_2)
```

Output:

```
In decreasing order -> As in your case [2.371979e+10 2.371979e+10 2.371979e+10]
In increasing order of x xoordinates [7.60444546e+09 1.72665695e+09 6.06409705e+08]
```

As you can understand now, you have to sort the df[x_col] and accordingly pass the df[y_col]
​

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, i sorted freq_data and everything works well now

Answer (score 1):

By default `np.interp` needs the `x` values to be sorted. If you do not want to sort your dataframe a workaround is to set the `period` argument to `np.inf`:

```
print(np.interp(0.4, freq_data['Percent_cum_freq'], freq_data['cum_OGIP'], period=np.inf))
```